# 3 dimensional array of characters?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to hold multiple "Attributes". Attributes have 5 different variables, all of which need to be stored as a string. I need to be able to access each variable with the attribute as a reference. Attributes do not need to be named anything in particular, just an index.

I tried using char pointers:

```
 char *attribute[0][4] = {
    "0x0201",
    "0x0000",
    "0x019",
    "0x0",
  };
  char *attribute[1][4] = {
    "0x0000",
    "0x0000",
    "0x001",
    "0x0",
  };
```

This says I'm re-declaring "attribute". How do I add a second attribute here without re-declaring.

Excuse my language etc, I'm fairly new to C and very new to pointers. If this isn't the best way to store the data I need to store, I'd be happy with any other suggestions. I've also tried a 3D array of chars but that ended with compiled code I was unable to upload to my arduino yun. I can provide that code if that's a better alternative to be pursuing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
char *attribute[][4] = { 
{"0x0201","0x0000", "0x019","0x0"}, 
{"0x0000","0x0000","0x001","0x0"} };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, would I reference this with 
    attribute[0][0];
to get "0x0201"?

Comment: Please see this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653510/create-2d-array-from-existing-1d-arrays-in-c/31656905#31656905), where I try to explain how C language arranges multidimensional arrays in memory. From it you can understand that the initialization of a multidimensional array simply follow the same principle: a row at time. The first `{` opens a set that is closed by corresponding `}`, then inside all initializers for that sub-array: a row. If you have more dimesions just surround each subset by braces and put other initializers. I hope my description is clear enough.