# Nested array initialization in C with LLVM

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, llvm

I'm initializing a nested array by passing each row separately.

The result is unexpected. See:

```
(gdb) li
1   #include <stdbool.h>
2   #include <stdio.h>
3   
4   bool sa1[2] = (bool [2]){true,  false};
5   bool sa2[2] = (bool [2]){false, false};
6   bool sa3[2] = (bool [2]){false, false};
7   
8   bool sa[3][2] = {sa1, sa2, sa3};
9   
10  int main() {
(gdb) print sa1
$1 = {true, false}
(gdb) print sa2
$2 = {false, false}
(gdb) print sa3
$3 = {false, false}
```

So far, all is as expected. However:

```
(gdb) print sa
$4 = {{true, true}, {true, false}, {false, false}}
```

I expected the value of `sa` to contain `sa1`, `sa2` and `sa3`, but it doesn't.

If I inline those expressions by hand, then it contains the expected values if I compile it with GCC, but not LLVM.

What is going on?

Comment: Don't you get compiler warnings?

Comment: First this doesn't have anything to do with gdb, and it's more likely you want to say you compiled with Clang, not LLVM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create 2D array from existing 1D arrays in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653510/create-2d-array-from-existing-1d-arrays-in-c)

Comment: See also: [c++ - creating 2d array from 1d arrays - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936040/creating-2d-array-from-1d-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

```
  bool sa[3][2] = {sa1, sa2, sa3};
```

It initiates this array with references to arrays `sa1`, `sa1`, `sa2` converted to `bool`.  And it compiles only because that those references are not `NULL` pointers thus they convert to `true`.

In standard C this should not even compile because static storage duration objects **have to* be inilized by **constant expressions**. Variable is not a **constant expression** so it some king of GCC extensi
on

Comment: Yeah, I thought that could be happening. I was trying to check that by printing the pointers, but it wasn't obvious to see.